# Authorization user actions using spring aop theory

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization, spring-aop

Today I want to ask about authorizing user actions. For example I've got a List containing all authorized users. Shall I now create an advice which shall search for all actions requiring authorization. Use @Around and check if user is authorized. Then call users method. Otherwise if user isn't authorized do nothing. Am I right? Are there any other ways to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work. You can also use Spring Security. It is a part of Spring framework. It also use AOP.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html

You can find a lot of tutorial on the Internet. Just google "spring security authorization tutorial"